# How to center a logo image inside a header

Tags: html, css

I would like a logo to appaear in the center of the navigation bar. At the moment i've made it really small just to ensure I can see it for now but will sort the size out afterwards.

Here is a photoshop design of how I want it to look:
https://gyazo.com/c1b0d25c4fe94a33edf3937576324229

Here is how it looks currently:
https://gyazo.com/4432c9c4874a082a9c4a4c5eb6d7af12

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

HTML:

```
<body id="chesters">

    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="Menu.html">Menu</a></li>
            <li><a href="Burritos.html">Burritos</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html"><img class="header-image" src="assets/Headerlogo1.png"></a></li>
            <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="About.html">About Us</a></li>   
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

<div id="Page">



</div> <!-- Page -->

</body>
```

CSS:

```
    body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    color: #666;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#Page {
    padding-top: 100px;
}


header {
    background-color: #1c1c1b;
    font-family: 'Century gothic';
    font-size: 180%;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #009641;
    border-bottom-width: 5px;
    position: fixed;
    line-height: 50px;
    z-index: 1000;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 0.8s ease;
}

.header-image {
    /*width: 100px;
    height: 400px;*/
    align-content: center;
    margin-top: -30px;
}


#center-column {
    background-color: white;
    width: 1080px;
    height: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #888888;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

nav {

}

nav ul {
    text-align: center;
    display: table;
}

nav li {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    /*display: inline;*/
    padding: 0 10px;
}

nav li a {
    color: #009641;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav li a:hover {
    color: #e2030e;
}
```

Comment: have you tried adding some margin and padding to the element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good morning!

Usually you want to control the `nav ul` and `nav ul li` elements appearance together without using floats and heavy padding. take a look at my revisions here. For the logo, you can just put it into an `li` element:

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    color: #666;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#Page {
    padding-top: 100px;
}


header {
    background-color: #1c1c1b;
    font-family: 'Century gothic';
    font-size: 180%;
    height: 140px;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #009641;
    border-bottom-width: 5px;
    position: fixed;
    line-height: 50px;
    z-index: 1000;
}

nav {
}
nav ul{
 text-align: center;
 display: table;
 }

nav li {
    display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
 padding: 0 10px;
}

nav li a {
    color: #009641;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav li a:hover {
    color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<body id="chesters">

    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="Menu.html">Menu</a></li>
            <li><a href="Burritos.html">Burritos</a></li>
     <li><img class="header-image" src="chesters.png"></li>
            <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="About.html">About Us</a></li>   
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

<div id="Page">



</div> <!-- Page -->

</body>
```

Try this revision.

Comment: Hi @scoopzilla This kind of worked but something is still not right. Here's how it looks now after making those changes https://gyazo.com/c50e24f4d151af0c804b35b29cda5ec4    My image file from photoshop was 100px height by 400px width and i removed all height/width stuff from the .header-image class

Comment: ah I added margin-top -30 to my image class and now it looks like this https://gyazo.com/e1c24195ff2db93db8d27e4c4de791c3 Image seems fine but anyway to sort the links out? thanks @scoopzilla

Comment: @EthanBristow Look a the revised code. Let's display the `ul` as a table and the `li` as a table-cell and vertically align. Again try to stay away from things like negative padding and floats :)

Comment: That's better, just need horizontal centering for the table. Here's how it looks now https://gyazo.com/4cb9b007b6a0c62b6924d29415ebf7d1 @scoopzilla

Comment: Did you copy the code exactly? There is a `text-align` in the nav-ul :)

Comment: yes, i'll update the question with the new code all together for you :)

Comment: yes, i've updated the question with the new code all together for you :) @scoopzilla

Comment: Nevermind thankyou i fixed it, I added margin: auto to the nav ul. Thanks very much for your help. If you don't mind me asking one more question, what's the problem with using margins/padding etc? @scoopzilla

Comment: In responsive layouts they cause nothing but trouble. They are okay to use, but you should rely on things like `display` styles to achieve the looks that you want :) [CSS Display Tutorials](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/). And Floats can be a total nightmare. Trust me, I have been there :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS:

```
nav ul {
  text-align: center;
}
```

The `li` elements shouldn't be affected but the image will be centered.

Answer (score 0):

Add container class before nav and set max-width and margin: 0 auto

```
 <body>
        <header>
            <div class="container">
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="Menu.html">Menu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Burritos.html">Takeaway Burritos</a></li>
                        <li><img class="header-image" src="assets/Headerlogo1.png"></li>
                        <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="About.html">About Us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div id="Page">
        </div>
        <!-- Page -->
    </body>
```

---

```
  body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    color: #666;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#Page {
    padding-top: 100px;
}

header {
    background-color: #1c1c1b;
    font-family: 'Century gothic';
    font-size: 180%;
    height: 140px;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #009641;
    border-bottom-width: 5px;
    position: fixed;
    line-height: 50px;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.container {
    max-width: 1282px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

nav {}

nav ul {
    text-align: center;
    display: table;
}

nav li {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

nav li a {
    color: #009641;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

nav li a:hover {
    color: #FFF;
}
```